# My addEventListener only listens to my last querySelector why?

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, addeventlistener, queryselector

Here is my JS code

```
async function panier() {
  let lineaProduct = localStorage.getItem("prod");
  let panier = JSON.parse(lineaProduct);
  console.log(panier)
  panier.forEach(async function (prod) {
    const rep = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/products/${prod.id}`)
    const product = await rep.json()
    document.getElementById('cart__items').innerHTML += `
      <article class="cart__item" data-id="${prod.id}" data-color="${prod.color}">
        <div class="cart__item__img">
            <img src="${product.imageUrl}" alt="Photographie d'un canapé">
        </div>
        <div class="cart__item__content">
          <div class="cart__item__content__description">
            <h2>${product.name}</h2>
              <p>${prod.color}</p>
              <p>${product.price * prod.quantity} €</p>
          </div>
          <div class="cart__item__content__settings">
            <div class="cart__item__content__settings__quantity">
              <p>Qté : ${prod.quantity} </p>
              <input type="number" class="itemQuantity" name="itemQuantity" min="${1}" max="${100}" value="${prod.quantity}">
              <div class="cart__item__content__settings__delete">
                <p class="deleteItem">Supprimer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>`

  let itemDelete = document.querySelector(`.cart__item[data-id="${prod.id}"][data-color="${prod.color}"] > .cart__item__content > .cart__item__content__settings > .cart__item__content__settings__quantity > .cart__item__content__settings__delete > p`)
  let htmlDelete = document.querySelector(`.cart__item[data-id="${prod.id}"][data-color="${prod.color}"]`)

  itemDelete.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // je récupère le local storage

    let tab = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("prod"))

    // je filtre le tableau du local storage pour supprimer le produit si il est égal au produit du tableau

    tab = tab.filter(produit => {
      if (prod.id == produit.id && prod.color == produit.color) {
        return false
      }
      return true
    })

    // je remets le tout dans le local storage et je suppr l'html corespondant

    localStorage.setItem("prod", JSON.stringify(tab))
    htmlDelete.remove()
  })

      // changer la quantité
      
  let pQty = document.querySelector(`.cart__item[data-id="${prod.id}"][data-color="${prod.color}"] > .cart__item__content > .cart__item__content__settings > .cart__item__content__settings__quantity > p`)
  let inputQty = document.querySelector(`.cart__item[data-id="${prod.id}"][data-color="${prod.color}"] > .cart__item__content > .cart__item__content__settings > .cart__item__content__settings__quantity > input`)
  inputQty.addEventListener('change', function (elem) {
    pQty.textContent = `Qté : ${elem.target.value}`
    let pPrice = document.querySelector(`.cart__item[data-id="${prod.id}"][data-color="${prod.color}"] > .cart__item__content > .cart__item__content__description > p:nth-child(3) `)
    pPrice.textContent = `${product.price * elem.target.value} €`
  })
})
}
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <title>Cart</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Plateforme incroyable de e-commerce">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/cart.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="limitedWidthBlockContainer informations">
        <div class="limitedWidthBlock">
          <ul>
            <li><img src="../images/icons/phone.svg" alt="logo de téléphone" class="informations__phone">01 23 45 67 89</li>
            <li><img src="../images/icons/mail.svg" alt="logo d'une enveloppe" class="informations__mail">support@name.com</li>
            <li><img src="../images/icons/adress.svg" alt="logo d'un point de géolocalisation" class="informations__address">01 23 45 67 89</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="limitedWidthBlockContainer menu">
        <div class="limitedWidthBlock">
          <a href="./index.html">
            <img class="logo" src="../images/logo.png" alt="Logo de l'entreprise">
          </a>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <a href="./index.html"><li>Accueil</li></a>
              <a href="./cart.html"><li>Panier</li></a>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img class="banniere" src="../images/banniere.png" alt="Baniere">
    </header>
    
    <main class="limitedWidthBlockContainer">
      <div class="limitedWidthBlock" id="limitedWidthBlock">
        <div class="cartAndFormContainer" id="cartAndFormContainer">
          <h1>Votre panier</h1>
          <section class="cart">
            <section id="cart__items">
             <!--  <article class="cart__item" data-id="{product-ID}" data-color="{product-color}">
                <div class="cart__item__img">
                  <img src="../images/product01.jpg" alt="Photographie d'un canapé">
                </div>
                <div class="cart__item__content">
                  <div class="cart__item__content__description">
                    <h2>Nom du produit</h2>
                    <p>Vert</p>
                    <p>42,00 €</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cart__item__content__settings">
                    <div class="cart__item__content__settings__quantity">
                      <p>Qté : </p>
                      <input type="number" class="itemQuantity" name="itemQuantity" min="1" max="100" value="42">
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart__item__content__settings__delete">
                      <p class="deleteItem">Supprimer</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </article> -->
            </section>
            <div class="cart__price">
              <p>Total (<span id="totalQuantity"><!-- 2 --></span> articles) : <span id="totalPrice"><!-- 84,00 --></span> €</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cart__order">
              <form method="get" class="cart__order__form">
                <div class="cart__order__form__question">
                  <label for="firstName">Prénom: </label>
                  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required>
                  <p id="firstNameErrorMsg"><!-- ci est un message d'erreur --></p>
                </div>
                <div class="cart__order__form__question">
                  <label for="lastName">Nom: </label>
                  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required>
                  <p id="lastNameErrorMsg"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="cart__order__form__question">
                  <label for="address">Adresse: </label>
                  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" required>
                  <p id="addressErrorMsg"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="cart__order__form__question">
                  <label for="city">Ville: </label>
                  <input type="text" name="city" id="city" required>
                  <p id="cityErrorMsg"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="cart__order__form__question">
                  <label for="email">Email: </label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
                  <p id="emailErrorMsg"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="cart__order__form__submit">
                  <input type="submit" value="Commander !" id="order">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    
    <footer>
      <div class="limitedWidthBlockContainer footerMain">
        <div class="limitedWidthBlock">
          <div>
            <img class="logo" src="../images/logo.png" alt="Logo de l'entreprise">
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>10 quai de la charente <br>75019 Paris 19</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Téléphone : 01 23 45 67 89</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Email : support@name.com</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="limitedWidthBlockContainer footerSecondary">
        <div class="limitedWidthBlock">
          <p>© Copyright 2021 - 2042 | Openclassrooms by Openclassrooms | All Rights Reserved | Powered by <3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  <script src="../js/cart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My itemDelete.addEventListener only listens to the last querySelector of itemDelete when I have several products in my cart (because it's a sofa selling site)

I have the impression that something is overwriting the first "itemDelete".

so my function to delete them or add quantity is also working only on the last "itemDelete".

Thanks in advance for your help

I tried with this but still the same problem

```
// je cherche l'élément html à supprimer
let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll(`.deleteItem`)
deleteButtons.forEach(function (deleteButton) {
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let artElem = event.target.closest(`.cart__item`)
    let idProd = artElem.dataset.id
    let colorProd = artElem.dataset.color

    let tab = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("prod"))

    // je filtre le tableau du local storage pour supprimer le produit si il est égal au produit du tableau

    tab = tab.filter(produit => {
      if (idProd == produit.id && colorProd == produit.color) {
        return false
      }
      return true
    })

    // je remets le tout dans le local storage et je suppr l'html corespondant

    localStorage.setItem("prod", JSON.stringify(tab))
    artElem.remove()
  })
  
})
```

Comment: Assigning to an element's `innerHTML` property causes the element's children to be rebuild, meaning they are different elements and will thus lose the previously added listeners. Try [`inserAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead. Did that fix your problem?

Comment: @OskarGrosser Thank you very much after two days of trying everything and anything I had not looked at the right side of my code

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).